# libavcodec.a(vc1dsp_mmx.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_9'

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04, libavcodec

I am building an shared object file in ubuntu(vagrant) that uses ffmpeg libraries(libavcodec.a, libavformat.a, libavutil.a). I first used the standard configure options to build ffmpeg and libraries from [trac.ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). But there was some issues with dynamic linking and I modified the configure options a little bit to add `--enable-shared` and `-fPIC` options.

```
However when I build my application I get 
/usr/bin/ld: /root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(vc1dsp_mmx.o): 
relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_9' can not be used when
 making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I used the following options in my configure to build ffmpeg

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include -fPIC" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-pic \
  --enable-shared
```

The build works fine on my MAC.

The following is my cmake file to build my application

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(extractor C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "extractor")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules)

set(EXTRACTOR_VERSION "${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH}")
set(target_dir "bin")

# set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g -std=99")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g")
# set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-Bsymbolic")


add_library(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} SHARED src/frame_extractor.c)

include_directories(".")
find_package(FFmpeg REQUIRED)

if (FFMPEG_FOUND)
    message("Found FFMPEG/LibAV libraries ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES}")
        message("include dirs ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    include_directories(${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES})
else (FFMPEG_FOUND)
    message("cant find libavcodec, libavformat or libavutil. add them manually!!")
endif (FFMPEG_FOUND)

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES})
# target_link_libraries (${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-lm")
# target_link_libraries (${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-lavcodec")

if(APPLE)
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-framework CoreServices")
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-framework CoreFoundation")
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-framework AudioToolbox")
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-framework VideoToolbox")
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-framework CoreAudio")
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-framework CoreMedia")
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-framework CoreVideo")
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-framework AVFoundation")
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "-framework Security")
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib)
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib)
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib)
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} /usr/lib/liblzma.dylib)
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} /usr/local/lib/libswresample.a)
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} /usr/local/Cellar/fdk-aac/0.1.6/lib/libfdk-aac.dylib)
    #target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} /usr/local/lib/libx264.dylib)
endif(APPLE)
# Add python dependencies -
# ERROR - It picks up the default version from the machine which is 2.7.10
find_package( PythonInterp 2.7 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)


message("GURU - python include dirs = ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("GURU - python include dirs = ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})



# Apple creates annoying dylib extension for shared libraries
if(APPLE)
    SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".so")
endif(APPLE)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
```

Thanks a lot for any help in resolving this.

Comment: .a files are not dynamic libraries (that's .so), they are static libraries. Are you trying to include a static lib in a dynamic one? Or are you linking against the wrong libraries (did you forget to delete the .a file after rebuilding the shared .so file)?

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot @RonaldS.Bultje. I just assumed cmake is picking the correct one. Once I deleted the .a files it automatically picked up the .so files.

Comment: Just in case somebody stumbles here to link *static* ffmpeg, make sure to add `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` to link flags along with `-fPIC`.

Comment: If here for OpenCV, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292968/error-when-installing-opencv-any-version-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Interestingly, your own CMakeLists.txt pointed me to the answer.

Uncomment

`set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-Bsymbolic")`